# Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' when updating the table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem when trying to update table after checking row. Not sure if the **"if"** statement is wrong, however I'm not quite sure, why the **UPDATE** sql is returning this error. I wouldn't be suprised if INSERT did that.

Here's part of code:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM players WHERE user_id = '$id'";
$result = $connect->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0)
{

    $sql = "UPDATE players SET user_id = '$Player->user_id', display_name = '$Player->display_name', attackPower = '$Player->attackPower]', defensePower = '$Player->defensePower'";
    if($connect->query($sql) === TRUE)
    {
        echo 'Table has been successfully updated.';
    }else{
        echo 'There has been a problem with updating the "players" table. <br>Error: '.$connect->error;
    }

}else{

    $sql = "INSERT INTO players(user_id, display_name, attackPower, defensePower) VALUES('$Player->user_id', '$Player->display_name', '$Player->attackPower', '$Player->defensePower')";
    if($connect->query($sql) === TRUE)
    {
        echo'Table has been successfully migrated.';

    }else{
        echo'Table migration has failed.';
    }

}

$connect->close();
```

**INSERT**ing is working just fine. I would appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: You need a `WHERE` on your `UPDATE`, or it's going to try to update every single row with those values.

Comment: As @aynber said, you have to put a WHERE condition in your update, and if the field "user_id" is a primary key, you don't need to update that field, something like "UPDATE table SET display_name = "XXX", attackPower = "XXX", defensePower = "XXX" WHERE user_id = XXX"

Comment: Thanks guys, WHERE fixed my problem. Dunno what I was thinking without it lol. And yes $id and $Player->user_id are the same, only $id is from SESSION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update query should look like:

```
    $sql = "UPDATE `players` SET `display_name` = '{$Player->display_name}', 
    `attackPower` = '{$Player->attackPower}', `defensePower` = '{$Player->defensePower'}  
    WHERE `user_id` = '{$Player->user_id}'";
```

Answer (score 0):

It cause an error because Identity columns are not updateable.
You can update every columns except them:

```
$sql = "UPDATE players SET display_name = '$Player->display_name', attackPower = '$Player->attackPower]', defensePower = '$Player->defensePower'";
```

Answer (score 0):

As **@aynber** and **@Julqas** said, problem was my sql was missing **WHERE condition**. Thanks for help.